How to return the top n from a dynamic column
                Wk 01   Wk 02   Wk 03   Wk 04   Wk 05   Wk 06   Wk 07   Wk 08   Wk 09
                                
                                

Amersham Town           N/A 2   2.5 3.5 3.75    3.78    3.7 3.82    3.82
Bagshot                 N/A 0.5 0.75    0.67    1   1.13    1   1   0.91
Bedfont FC          N/A 3   2.5 3   2.8 2.83    2.57    2.75    3
Berks County            N/A 2   3.33    3.5 3.2 3   3   2.86    2.63
British Airways         N/A 2.5 2.5 2.17    2.14    1.88    1.89    1.9 1.9
Brook House         N/A 0.5 2   1.67    1.57    1.38    1.67    1.5 1.5
Eversley & California   N/A 2   2.5 3   2.4 2.5 2.43    2.25    2.25
FC Deportivo Galicia    N/A 1   2   2.6 2.6 2.17    2   2   2
Hillingdon Borough  N/A 4.5 2.75    2.4 1.86    1.75    1.67    1.67    1.67
From the table above, how would I return the top 3 from Wk 03 if today related to Wk 03. Tomorrow it could be Wk 04 (determined form a separate vlookup).
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-px5BbSk73bbyd5FapSyStD3MIXyHK4w2n4g42RE5uA/edit?usp=sharing
Example from above plus desired result can be found on the link above.
Thank you.
I have tried to place the suggested answer into the actual sheet. The error is "No matches are found in the FILTER evaluation"
What have I done wrong please?
enter image description here


Here's one possible logic you may test out:
=let(n,3,x,"Wk 03", Σ,filter(A4:J14,A1:J1=x),
     Λ,hstack(index(rank(Σ,Σ)),A4:A14,Σ),sort(filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)<=n)))



Change the n and x values at the start of formula as needed


Thanks.
When this goes live, there will be a lookup for Today's date which will return a Week No.
Can it be automatic that your formula looks up the Wk No from Row A? ie, where your formula is "Wk 03" ....that needs to look to a cell (M9 in this example).
Hope that makes sense.

worked out 'x' thanks - what is 'n' ?

n is to filter top n rank/values

I see now, thank you they are named. Could you look at the image in the initial question please? I have obviously not changed something correctly.

Hard to troubleshoot from a screenshot. Do recreate this in your test sheet so that I can check it out directly & all...

Ok, I have got that ready.

try: =let(n,30,x,B2, Σ,filter(E5:AS350,E2:AS2=x),Λ,hstack(index(rank(Σ,Σ)),D5:D350,Σ),sort(filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)<=n))) the ranges are unequal in the first filter function

Final question.
How to change the formula to rank small to large please?

rank formula 3rd parameter deals with ascending/desc order. Do checkout the formula documentation
